# How to compare two dates having format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dates with format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. When i use < or > to compare ,i am getting wrong results.I have tried new date('dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss') and comparing them still i am getting wrong results.

Can any one help please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your current code. Also, have you tried debugging it yourself?

Comment: Use `.getTime()` to compare them(it returns an integer value corresponding to the date). [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

Comment: If you are asking to validate than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222090/how-do-i-validate-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-format

Comment: I got it thank you.The format should be yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss to compare.

Comment: kindly please pass on the reason why you have down voted my question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert them to `Date` objects. However, since you're using a date with the dd/mm/yyyy format it won't really work. (By default `Date` uses the ISO 8601 format - yyyy-mm-dd. So you need to convert the format to something javascript can understand.

```
// convert to a parseable date string:
var dateStrA = "28/12/2013 16:20:22".replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3");
var dateStrB = "28/12/2013 16:20:11".replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3");

// now you can compare them using:
new Date(dateStrA) > new Date(dateStrB);
```

A bit messy, but does the trick.

Beware that comparing using equals, such as `===` will not work on `Date` objects. You can also use `Date.compare()` or casting to numbers or call .getDate() on the date

Comment: Thank you :). previously i am using split and joining the dates according to the required format.But your code simply awesome only two lines of code.

Comment: this answer did the trick in pure JavaScript, I like it :D

Comment: i did n't check it,because my application uses jquery also

Answer (score 1):

**"dd/mm/yyyy"** is the wrong format in Date string parsing, please revise it to **'mm/dd/yyyy'**, month need to be placed before day, then you could compare it directly, for instance:

```
a_time = new Date('30/12/2013 12:12:12');
//Mon Dec 30 2013 12:12:12 GMT+0800 (CST)

b_time = new Date('30/12/2013 12:12:13');
//Mon Dec 30 2013 12:12:13 GMT+0800 (CST)

a_time > b_time
//false

b_time > a_time
//true
```

### if you insist use the format "dd/mm/yyyy"

you could use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse any specific format to date object:

```
a = moment('30/12/2013 01:02:03', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
b = moment('30/12/2013 01:02:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')

a > b
//false
a < b
//true
```

if you prefer to compare by origin JavaScript objects, just use `toDate()` method to get the `Date()` object:

```
a = moment('30/12/2013 01:02:03', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate()
//Sat Mar 02 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
b = moment('30/12/2013 01:02:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate()
//Sat Mar 02 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
a > b
//false
a < b
//true
```

Comment: Why is your example code opposite of what you told the original poster not to do.  Which is it mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: I'm pointing out the format which is used by poster is wrong.

Comment: maybe you're right, the poster might not to change the format of the time string, let me edit my answer.

Comment: I got it thank you.The format should be yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss to compare