# Javascript date comparison for dynamically created HTML table rows

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, date-comparison

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" id="data_table" width="50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Due date</th>
      <th width="26%">Amount Due</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="addPurchaseItem">
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">
        <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="Text1" autocomplete="off" class="datectrl" name="due_date[]" placeholder="Due Date" runat="server" />
      </td>
      <td width="25%">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="new_Amount_1" placeholder="0.00" autocomplete="off" clientidmode="Static" name="new_Amount[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="return delete_row(this)" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="add_row('addPurchaseItem');" value="Add Credit Period" id="btnAddCrdPrd" name="addbtnAddCrdPrd" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datectrl").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',      
      showOn: 'focus'
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var count = 2;
  var limits = 500;

  function add_row(divName) {

    if (count == limits) {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + count + "inputs ");
    } else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
      var tabin = "new_due_" + count;
      tabindex = count * 1,
        tab1 = tabindex + 1;
      tab2 = tabindex + 2;
      newdiv.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" onchange="dateValidation()" name ="due_date[]" id = "new_due_' + count + '" class="datectrl" autocomplete="off" tabindex = "' + tab1 + '"  placeholder = "Due date" /> </td > <td> <input type="text" id="new_Amount_' + count + '" tabindex="' + tab1 + '" placeholder="0.00" autocomplete="off" name="new_Amount[]" /> </td><td> <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delete_row(this)" tabindex="' + tab2 + '"></input></td > ';
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      document.getElementById(tabin).focus();
      count++;
      $(".datectrl").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
      });
      $(".datectrl").focus();
    }
  }

  function delete_row(no) {
    var i = no.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    if (i == "1") {
      alert("Can't Delete Row");
      return false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("data_table").deleteRow(i);
    }
  }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function dateValidation() {
    $(function() {
      $("[id*=data_table] tbody ").each(function() {

        if ($(this).find('tr:eq(1) td:eq(0) input').val() <= $(this).find('tr:eq(0) td:eq(0) input').val()) {
          alert("Due date should be greater than previous due date");
          $(this).find('tr:eq(1) td:eq(0) input').val('');
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    });
  }

</script>
```

I have created a dynamic Html table(on button click it will add rows to the table). In due date column second row date should not be less than or equal to first row date. Like wise every dynamically added row date should check previous row date.

In `Onchange` event I created a validation for checking second row date is greater than previous row date. I have already tried `Date.parse` and `.getTime()` . I'm getting output correct but only for same month. For example if I enter 18/09/2019 in first row and 11/09/2019 in second row it showing error message that's correct but when I enter 11/10/2019 also it showing error. From my code I think its only checking date not month or year.

I have included my `Jsfiddle` Link
https://jsfiddle.net/Muthu15/as3t96jr/5/

Second row date should be greater than first row date and like wise every row should check previous row.

I updated my code https://jsfiddle.net/Muthu15/ugv0pw93/ now its working fine but I need to compare every rows which added. Like if I add third row it should compare with second row. I used multiple if conditions help me with that change that into single loop conditon.

Comment: Put the code in your question. (This site has its own snipplets that can run)

Comment: Sounds like you are comparing strings and not dates.

Comment: how to do that? i don't know that . i wrote this code using many websites. Help me please @epascarello

Comment: Plenty of questions on comparing dates.... First result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812161/how-to-compare-two-dates-having-format-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-in-jquery

Comment: thank you. i updated my code. https://jsfiddle.net/Muthu15/ugv0pw93/  Now i have some other issue please help me. In my validation i used many if conditions to check current row with previous row change that to single loop @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mind. I did some changes to your Fiddle, I added a `MomentJS` CDN and I change the validation so that the comparison can be made between date objects instead of `strings`. I think that should do the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/msn0w46b/

As they told you above, I suggest you use `MomentJS` to work with dates in Javascript.

Now, I think that your problem will be when you add more than two columns to your grid since in in the code, it can be seen that you're only comparing the first two rows.

Comment: thank you so much its working but i have two doubts please help me @Leonardo Herrera Ornelas

Comment: yes i need to compare every rows which added. Like if i add third row it should compare with second row@Leonardo

Comment: is there any way that i can do this without momentJS@Leonardo

Comment: @Muthu As a quick solution, you could put all your date inputs a common class, then in your `onClick` event, you could make a loop over all the inputs that has the class you named your date inputs with, then in each iteration you can figure out a way to get the value of the same class but one index before the one you're iterating over.

Comment: Right now I can't think of a way to do it without `MomentJS`. Only if you make your own function using the javascript `Date` class to manually convert string to date objects and compare them.

Comment: i updated my code based on your edit. My Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Muthu15/as3t96jr/10/  But I need help to change this multiple if condition to single for loop.@Leonardo

Comment: okay I use MomentJs its working fine. But help me with this loop !!@Leonardo

Comment: thanks bro it perfectly worked in my project@Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it looks like you are comparing strings rather than dates. Try parsing your strings into [Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) before the comparison. I also highly recommend the [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) library for helping deal with dates in JS.

Comment: tell me how to do that. comparing two dates by date format not by string. and please tell me without libraries. In my project i can't use libraries.@ElliotSchmelliot

Comment: Checkout the JS Date constructor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. The MomentJS library is completely optional.